# Check if string contains only lowercase letters and underscores

Tags: php, regex, validation

I would like to check if a given string contains only lowercase letters and underscores. It may not contain whitespaces, numbers, uppercase letters, or special symbols/characters.

- `my_name_is_John_Doe` = Fail (no uppercase)
- `my_name_is john doe` = Fail  (no white-space)
- `my_name_is_john_doe` = OK
- `i_am_20_years_old` = Fail (no numbers)
- `i'm_cool!` Fail (no characters like: !"#$%&/., etc.)

One extra rule: no accented/multibyte letters like `ä`, `ö`, etc.

Comment: Your pattern is super simple, you just need `[a-z_]`

Comment: Use: `/^[a-z_]+$/`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iL7fC6/1

Comment: You should try and show some attempt done by you, before asking for a solution.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Yes, Murlidhar. I agree, definitely. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply use:

```
/^[a-z_]+$/
```

For description and more examples you can visit [here](http://www.noupe.com/development/php-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match()` or a non-regex approach that removes all whitelisted characters and checks if any characters are leftover.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JdgIn))

```
$strings = [
    'my_name_is_John_Doe',
    'my_name_is john doe',
    'my_name_is_john_doe',
    'i_am_20_years_old',
    "i'm_cool!"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo json_encode([
             $string,
             !strlen(ltrim($string, 'a..z_')),
             !preg_match('/[a-z_]*[^a-z_]/', $string)
         ]);
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
["my_name_is_John_Doe",false,false]

["my_name_is john doe",false,false]

["my_name_is_john_doe",true,true]

["i_am_20_years_old",false,false]

["i'm_cool!",false,false]
```

In terms of step performance, here is a table of working patterns for each provided sample string:

| string | match /^[a-z_]+$/ | don't match /[^a-z_]/ | don't match /.*[^a-z_]/ | don't match /[a-z_]*[^a-z_]/ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my_name_is_John_Doe | 13 | 13 | 6 | 3 |
| my_name_is john doe | 12 | 12 | 7 | 3 |
| my_name_is_john_doe | 4 | 20 | 23 | 40 |
| i_am_20_years_old | 7 | 7 | 14 | 3 |
| i'm_cool! | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 |

The above table is purely an academic offering.  On input strings of such small size, any performance gains or losses will be indistinguishable to human end users.  In other words, this task is highly unlikely to be the performance bottleneck for your application, so choose a technique that you understand and can maintain.